# jquery, columns equal heights and at least as tall as the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following bit of jquery to make the two main columns on my page the same height.

```
var $toEqualize = $('.equalheightbox');
$toEqualize.css('height', (function(){
    return Math.max.apply(null, $toEqualize.map(function(){
        return $(this).height();
    }).get());
})());
```

Which works great except if the content of either div isn't big enough to stretch to the bottom of the page then the two columns are the same height but there's an unsightly gap at the bottom of my page. I'd like the columns to be the same height but also to be at least as tall as the browser window being used to show the page.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but that should do it:

```
var $toEqualize = $('.equalheightbox');
var wS = $(window).height();
$toEqualize.css('height', (function(){
    return Math.max.apply(null, $toEqualize.map(function(){
        return wS > $(this).height() ? wS : $(this).height();
    }).get());
})());
```

For explainations:
$(window).height() is the height of the screen of the client (if you want less, check for the height of the parent.

wS > $(this).height() ? wS : $(this).height() // that will select at least the height of the screen (this expression is a shorthand for if (...) { ... } else { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a container for both div, set them to have the full height of the parent and let them grow.